# how can I access the value of a service ticket from kerberos cache?

Tags: kerberos, kerberos-delegation

I'm trying to debug an issue in kerberos configuration. I generated a service ticket using the `kgetcred` utility. I'd like to access the value of the service ticket so that I can put it into the Authorization header of a request to the protected resource.

I ran the following:

```
kinit myUser
kgetcred HTTP/myProtectedResource@MY.DOMAIN.COM
```

I can see the ticket exists by running

```
$klist
Credentials cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
        Principal: myUser@MY.DOMAIN.COM

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Jan 30 15:37:39 2017  Jan 31 01:37:39 2017  krbtgt/MY.DOMAIN.COM@MY.DOMAIN.COM
Jan 30 16:02:39 2017  Jan 31 01:37:39 2017  HTTP/myProtectedResource@MY.DOMAIN.COM
```

I had a look inside the /tmp/krb5cc_1000 file, but this seems encrypted of encoded somehow.

How can I get the value of this ticket to put in the Authorization header when making an HTTP request to the protected resource?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the value of this ticket"?  What kind of value are you trying to get?

Comment: I mean the string I need to pass in the Authorisation header to access the resource.